# Android adb won't let me enter commands

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to deal with some SQLiteDB issues and wanted to use the ABD tool to access my emulators database.  When I click on the adb file in the platform-tool file, it opens up but very quickly throws a bunch of text on the window and then closes.  Its so fast I can't even tell what it is doing. I tried running as administrator and it didn't change.  I'm using Vista if that has anything to do with it.

Any suggestions for how I can even get it to stop from closing so I can enter a command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You start the command shell (<kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, enter `cmd` in the window that appears and hit Enter.), then use it from there. `adb shell` is probably the command you need.

`C:\> cd \Path\to\platform-tools`
`C:\Path\to\platform-tools\> adb shell`

if you add the path to your environment `PATH` you don't need to `cd` there. [[This](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/06/22/modify-a-users-path-in-windows-vista-vista-path-environment-variable)] should be a good example how to do that.

Comment: @zapi I managed to start adb.exe but it still wouldn't stay open...
I hit Windows + R then typed C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\> adb shell

Comment: but you should see what it prints, no?

Comment: It prints a bunch of stuff but then closes the window

Comment: oops, I forgot that you have to have to start `cmd` in the window, the next thing you get is that black window that always closes

Comment: I tried the previous C:\Program Files .... \platform-tools\adb shell and got a command window with just a # at the top

Comment: that's the device shell, you can enter commands there. e.g. `ls /data/data/your.package/databases/` to show you the files in your app directory. Instead of `adb shell` you may want to do `adb pull /data/data/your.package/databases/database.name` then to download the database from your device to your pc

Comment: Wow this is more complicated than it seems... I will keep working at it and see what I can find.  Thanks for your help. If I pull it, where will it go?

Comment: the directory you are in at that moment, probably your `platform-tools` directory

Comment: Simply execute `set "PATH=%PATH%;path\to\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;path\to\Android\Sdk\tools"` to add adb and the other stuff to the `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by zapl, you need to launch command prompt, add adb directory to path and then running adb commands. You may also be able to pull the trick with DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

In the answer, it was not clear that you have to run a windows cmd.exe terminal program first. Make sure you are in the correct directory, Then start ADB from within this cmd program.

To ensure that windows can find adb.exe ("being in the correct directory), you can either navigate to the location of the adb.exe (usually Platform tools) manually using "cd" command, or update your path statement so that windows can find it regardless of where your cmd.exe prompt is pointing.